# Calling mouseDouble click event from e.Key in c#- How can it be done?

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, mouseevent

I'm a newbie programmer and code in C# (WPF actually). I have a problem with my code and wondered if you could help.

I need to add a `DoubleClick` to the switch `e.Key` that already exist. The code is something like this:

```
private void txtMainInput(object sender, keyEventArgs e)
{
    ...
    switch (e.key)
    {
        case Key.Enter:
                OnInput_EnterDown();
        break;

        case Key.Tab:
                OnInput_TabDown();
        break;

        case MouseDoubleClick:
                OnInput_DoubleClick();

        break;

        default:
        break;
   }
}
```

`Problem is` that the `third case` doesn't really exist, as the key derives from `keyboardEventArgs` and `mouseDoubleclick` derives from `mouseEventArgs`, thus I can't call `MouseDoubleClick`. How can I overcom this?

Comment: You can subscribe to MouseDoubleClick event
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.controls.control.mousedoubleclick.aspx
and do the operation there.

Comment: but how do i combine it with the e.key switch?

Comment: you can write a custom EventArgs and write another method to wrap mouse event and key event together and then handle all events at one place with switch

Answer (score 1):

The reason the 3rd one doesn't exist is because KeyEventArgs is return on a KeyDown/KeyPress event ***of the keyboard*** not of the mouse...

To subscribe to mouse clicks you need another event such as `MouseDoubleClick` and put whatever logic you want there:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        txtMainInput.MouseDoubleClick += txtInput_MouseDoubleClick;
    }

    void txtInput_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        // Put doubleClick logic here
    }
```

In the same way you can subscribe to `MouseDown`, `MouseUp` etc... Since you tagged this as WPF, this can also be done in XAML....

Comment: so, there's no way to combine the keyboard and the mouse (I knew that, thanks) in the same switch???

Comment: This is the *correct* way. That said, you can always create your own method which receives a regular "EventArgs" call it whenever a keydown or mousedown event is raised. Then, in your method check which kind of EventArgs is it (Mouse or Key) etc... But it kind of smells of bad code :P